# Add all items from .each into hidden field

Tags: jquery

I am running a loop which gets text values. I want to put them into a hidden field but currently it only adds one item instead of all of them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".person-name").each(function(index) {
      var names = $(this).text();
      $('.names').val(names);
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: You likely want to run that on submit and not on load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `val()` overwrites any pre-existing value. As such only the final value set in the loop will be shown.

To fix this you could use `map()` to create an array of the values, then use `join()` when displaying it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var names = $(".item-title").map(function(index) {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    $('.names').val(names.join(','));
  }, 1000);
});
```